# Dataset for stock indices including ticker symbol and sector

Tags: data-request, finance, stock

For Dax30 there is a great (small) dataset including all firms of index (DAX30), the corresponding ticker symbol and sector:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAX -->Zusammensetzung (first three columns)

```
Name    Symbol  Branche 
Adidas  ADS     Bekleidung  
Allianz ALV     Versicherungen  
BASF    BAS     Chemie
```

**Question:**

Is there an equivilant dataset for S&P500, EuroStoxx 600, MSCI world, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found links for S&P500:
https://www.slickcharts.com/sp500 and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies.

DAX30 was already mentioned:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAX